# money converter c++ gives bracket errors

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Which currency do you wanna exchange for, $? €? or ¥?:\n";

    string currency;
    string dollars;
    string euros;
    string yen;

    char $;
    char €;
    char ¥;
    
    if (cin >> $);
        cout << "You have chosen dollars.\n";
        cout << "Please enter your amount:\n";
        int amount;
        cin >> amount;
        cout << "Your amount is:" << amount*153 << "PKR" << endl;
    
 keep_window_open();
 return 0;

}
```

I tried making a money converter but my code till dollar wont run so I haven't wrote euro or yen yet. thank you for the response.

Comment: You definitely should read some of C++ books.

Comment: `#include"std_lib_facilities.h"` is from a book. One thing about c++ is that guessing on syntax and behavior may lead unexpected results for code that compiles.

Comment: For this you don't want 3 char variables. You want a single variable and you want to compare it to each of the 3 choices: '$' ... Secondly unlike some other languages indentation does not define a scope. You need to use brackets in the if () { // scope ...} also like the answer says the `;` placed at the end of the `if ()` ended the if block nothing will happen if the if is true or false. The next line will execute regardless because its not part of the if

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't use those symbols as variable names, since they're not ASCII characters and could get messed up.

Secondly, `if (cin >> $);` doesn't do what you think it does. All it does reads something into the `$` variable, and moves on regardless of what cin actually read because the if statement is terminated by a semicolon. The code after that is going to get executed, regardless of what cin actually read. Instead, you should do

```
if (condition) {
    thing to execute if condition is true
}
```

Note the use of curly braces.

Thirdly, this is not how you check if the input string matches the dollar sign. What you should do instead, is read the input into a variable, and then compare that variable to the currency symbols.